# IOS XMPP register new user

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, chat, openfire

i am using xcode 6.2 ios sdk 8.2 ,create chat application using XMPP and OpenFire Server 3.9.3, now i am trying to register new user with this method

```
 -(BOOL)registerWithElements:(NSArray *)elements error:(NSError **)errPtr
```

but in this method supportsInBandRegistration return NO

```
- (BOOL)supportsInBandRegistration
{
__block BOOL result = NO;

dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {

    // The root element can be properly queried for authentication mechanisms anytime after the
    // stream:features are received, and TLS has been setup (if required)
    if (state >= STATE_XMPP_POST_NEGOTIATION)
    {
        NSXMLElement *features = [rootElement elementForName:@"stream:features"];
        NSXMLElement *reg = [features elementForName:@"register" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"];

        result = (reg != nil);
    }
}};

if (dispatch_get_specific(xmppQueueTag))
    block();
else
    dispatch_sync(xmppQueue, block);

return result;
}
```

how enable supportsInBandRegistration ?

sign Up code

```
  NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"abc"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"123"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"abc xyz"]];
[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"accountType" stringValue:@"3"]];
// [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"deviceToken" stringValue:@"7316E42C-160F-46E2-8980-026C682F1B97"]];

[elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@bbc.com"]];


[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
```

thanks